# Configuration - Nginx with multiple sites in subfolders

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, nginx, configuration, vps

I want to install my vps to develop multiple websites at the same time.
My root directory structure:

```
/var/www/html/web1;
/var/www/html/web2;
/var/www/html/wordpress1;
/var/www/html/wordpress1;
/var/www/html/drupal1;
/var/www/html/drupal2;
```

I want to link to the website http://123.123.123.123/drupal1 and 123.123.123.123 is the IP of the VPS.

Now whenever I add a website I have to edit the config file. Is there a way to install it for every page?

Here is my nginx config:

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;
root /var/www/html;
index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;
server_name _;
location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
try_files $uri =404;
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
fastcgi_index index.php;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
include fastcgi_params;
}

location @sub_rewrite {
rewrite ^/drupal1/(.*)$ /drupal1/index.php?$1;
}

location /drupal1/ {
try_files $uri @sub_rewrite;
}
}
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Could you please explain one more time what exactly you want to achieve? Currently it's not clear enough

Comment: As you can be found at my config. I'm lost 6 line to install page "drupal1". If I have 100 website, config file will be long. How to make shorter config?

Comment: How about moving common parts into external file and then use 'include' directive? And probably you will have to rework part of configuration to cover uncommon parts with regexps

Comment: I tried using "/(.*)/index.php" to configure the entire subdirectory but it does not work